# Reading line by line and fetch word from line in C++

Tags: c++, getline

```
string line;
string filename;
cout << "Please enter filename :" << endl;
cin >> filename;
ifstream myfile(filename);
/*cout << "Please enter the name of file that you write results : "<< endl;
cin >> wfile; */
if(myfile.is_open())
{

    while(getline(myfile,line))
    {
        convert(line);

    }

    //getline(myfile,line);
    //pushintoVector(line,buffer);
}
else
{
    cout << "Error : File could not be opened" << endl;

}

try{
myfile.close();
myFile.close();
}catch(exception &e1)
{
    cout << endl;
}
//system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

After that i want to send current line to another function like:

```
void convert(string lines)
{
    myFile.open("yazici.txt");

    string buf;
     string convertingnum;
    istringstream ss(lines);

    while(ss >> buf)
    {
```

So how can i read word from a line and change it according to if-else structure and write it another file.Edit: Also is there a function or method to determine line length ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the output file at the same time you open the input file.
2. Pass the output stream as an argument to `convert` instead of opening the file every time in the function.
3. Use better names than `myfile` and `myFile`.

```
ifstream inputFile(filename);
ofstream outputFile("yazici.txt");

if(inputFile.is_open())
{
   while(getline(inputFile,line))
   {
      convert(outputFile, line);
   }
}
```

and ...

```
void convert(std::ostream& outputFile,
             string lines)
{
   string buf;
   string convertingnum;
   istringstream ss(lines);

   while(ss >> buf)
   {
       outputFile << buf << std::endl; //???
   }
}
```

Comment: Can i write like this: if(buf==good) { convertingnum=bad; outputFile << convertingnum; ???